# How do I switch from Python2 to Python3 in Sublime Text

Tags: python, sublimetext

When I try running python script in (CTRL-B or CMD-B) Sublime Text, it runs the script in Python2. but how can I run my script in Python3 in Sublime Text?

Comment: what is your system? Do you have python3 installed? Change your system `PATH` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, go to Tools > Build System > New Build System..., this will open a new file called untitled.sublime-build. In this file, you need copy-paste/type this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["python3.6", "-i", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Now, on my system, I have my PATH configured so the command python3.6 runs Python 3.6.4. Your installation may differ, so you have to change that bit to how you run Python 3 on your system. You can use either the full absolute path to the interpreter or the command you use from the command line to run Python 3.

After you've done that, save the file as Python3.sublime-build in the folder Sublime suggests and you should be ready to go. You can use the options in Tools > Build System to change build systems manually, but Sublime should suggest this build whenever you open a Python file from now on.